# For loop KeyError: 4675 when making corpus from Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keyerror, corpus

I've tried to make corpus from Pandas dataframe (with shape (14454, 9)).
However, whenever the range exceeds 10k, the for loop return KeyError: 4675 , yet works well for 10k below.

```
# getting the entire text
# this works fine
corpus=" "

for i in range(0,998):
    corpus= corpus+ ' ' + df["Cleaned_text"][i]
```

```
# this return Keyerror:4675  
corpus=" "

for i in range(0,14453):
    corpus= corpus+ ' ' + df["Cleaned_text"][i]
```

any ideas there clear this with thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use iloc function

```
#getting the entire resume text

corpus=" "

for i in range(0,14454):
    corpus= corpus+ ' ' + df["Cleaned_Resume"].iloc[i]
```

sr for my newbie but still keep as someone might need it